# Is Float video view available in Android Youtube API

Tags: android, api, youtube

Developing my android app using Youtube **APIs** and looking to add all the features that **YouTube** provides on its actual APP.

There is a new feature, when Video is playing and if we will go back that video will float to right bottom corner.

How to achieve this feature.I **dont want** to use any **thrid-party library**.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please put the documentation of the new feature

Comment: @TOP [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IinfQ.jpg)
similar like this link

Comment: You can try to use `WindowManager` for displaying video in  a pop-up window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to undertand what is API. API - it's like bridge between server and client.

From Wikipedia:

> In computer programming, an application programming interface (API) is a set of subroutine definitions, protocols, and tools for building application software. In general terms, it's a set of clearly defined methods of communication between various software components. A good API makes it easier to develop a computer program by providing all the building blocks, which are then put together by the programmer. An API may be for a web-based system, operating system, database system, computer hardware, or software library. An API specification can take many forms, but often includes specifications for routines, data structures, object classes, variables, or remote calls. POSIX, Microsoft Windows API, the C++ Standard Template Library, and Java APIs are examples of different forms of APIs. Documentation for the API is usually provided to facilitate usage. The status of APIs in intellectual property law is controversial.

So it's just way to communicate to dedicated part of internet. And you need some library to do this floating window. Some services providing SDK (development kit) with helper tools to create app that will be connected to this service, but as far as I know YouTube don't have it.

Take a look at [this library](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel), maybe it's what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Ekalips. 
But that library ,its a third party library.
i dont want to use a thirdparty library in my app.

Comment: @ananya so create your own custom `View` that will handle all. I assume you need fragment, with some on touch handler (to handle swipe down) so you can minimize `VideoView`. Also you should use fragmentTransition with add, this way background fragment will be still visible and active after adding `VideoView` one.

Comment: Fragment means in xml file i need to declar like below??

 
 <fragment
 android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
Is it correct?

Then in my mainactivity i need to do like below
  youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment)getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);

can u please tell me is it correct or not?

Comment: No, you need to create your own fragment